# Combine row data from multiple txt files to a single data frame in column format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have row data in each text file in the following format

File 1

```
   Sample 1, 24/07/2017 13:26:08
0  Peak at 1219 , 1.864
1  Peak at 1092 , 0.412
2  Peak at 1358 , 1.661
```

File 2

```
   Sample 2, 24/07/2017 14:28:15
0  Peak at 1219 , 1.544
1  Peak at 1092 , 0.315
2  Peak at 1358 , 1.564
```

File 3

```
   Sample 3, 24/07/2017 15:31:05
0  Peak at 1219 , 1.954
1  Peak at 1092 , 0.524
2  Peak at 1358 , 1.423
```

I want to combine the data from all the files and create a single data frame in a column format like this.

```
  Sample No  Date        Time      Peak at 1219  Peak at 1092  Peak at 1358 
0     1      24/07/2017  13:26:08    1.864        0.412          1.661
1     2      24/07/2017  13:28:15    1.544        0.315          1.564
2     3      24/07/2017  13:31:05    1.954        0.524          1.423
```

Can anyone please help with a code. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is main function [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), which create big `df`. But need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for align data.

Then transpose `df` by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and convert second level selected by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

For first and second column use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) and [`DatetimeIndex.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.time.html).

Last remove second level by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`, [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for column name and last `reset_index` again:

```
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
#set first column to index
dfs = [x.set_index(x.columns[0]) for x in dfs]

df = pd.concat(dfs, 1, keys = range(1, len(dfs) + 1)).T
print (df)
                       Peak at 1219  Peak at 1092  Peak at 1358
1 24/07/2017 13:26:08         1.864         0.412         1.661
2 24/07/2017 14:28:15         1.544         0.315         1.564
3 24/07/2017 15:31:05         1.954         0.524         1.423

print (df.index.labels[0])
FrozenNDArray([0, 1, 2], dtype='int8')

dates = pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(1))
df.insert(0, 'Date', dates.date)
df.insert(1, 'Time', dates.time)
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename_axis('Sample No').reset_index()
print (df)
   Sample No        Date      Time  Peak at 1219  Peak at 1092  Peak at 1358
0          1  2017-07-24  13:26:08         1.864         0.412         1.661
1          2  2017-07-24  14:28:15         1.544         0.315         1.564
2          3  2017-07-24  15:31:05         1.954         0.524         1.423
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer @jezrael.This works well when i have 3 files, where we can define set_index for 3 samples of files. What if i have n sample files. How would i create the dfs for that ? Appreciate your help once again.

Comment: Sure i will @jezrael. Just need a bit more help with multiple files. Can you help with that? Thank you

Comment: Sure, I dont see it. you can use `dfs = [df1,df2,df3, dfn]` and then `dfs = [x.set_index(x.columns[0]) for x in dfs]` if need select always first column to index

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. It really helped. I have included this part in my python script where i am reading and merging multiple txt files and creating a big data frame. The only problem which i am facing is , all the row entries of column  "Sample No" is 1. Each row shows a sample no but its printing only sample no 1 . Can you advice how to correct? Thanks

Comment: Is possible use parameter `keys=range(dfs)` in `concat` ?

Comment: I have tried, its not working, Can you check if possible? I have looked up for some exaples but couldnt really find something. Thanks once again @jezrael

Comment: Ok, what exactly is problem? If use my solution with `df = pd.concat(dfs, 1, keys = range(1, len(dfs) + 1)).T` it not create first level of index with sample numbers? What is after `df = pd.concat(dfs, 1, keys = range(1, len(dfs) + 1)).T` if check `print (df.index.labels)` ?

Comment: I edit answer with information about labels - `1,2,3` are sample numbers. Can you check it?